# Hiding of label in Xcode is not working properly in my tableviewcell of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, label, hidden

I am having two labels created manually for displaying it in the tableviewcell named title and detail, code for displaying it are,

```
dealarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];

detailarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"oneoneoneoneone oneoneoneoneoneoneoooooooo",@"two",@"three",@"fouronefouronefouronefouronefouronefouronefouron",nil];

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            for(UILabel *lbl in [cell.contentView subviews])
        {

            [lbl removeFromSuperview];


        }
        cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        UILabel* title;

        title= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,300,20)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
        [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:title];
        [title setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
        title.tag = 1001;
        title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        title.text =[dealarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel* detail;
        detail= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,30,300,10)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:detail];
        [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:detail];
        [detail setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        detail.tag = 1002;
        detail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        detail.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        detail.text = [detailarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell
 }
```

No problem in displaying those 2 labels and no problem in hiding all the 'detail' label and displaying the 'title' alone, the problem arises when I try to display the 'detail' label of the resp selective of cells.

Code tried:

```
 // conti of cellforrowatindexpath
 detail.numberOfLines = 3;
   detail.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    if (a==-1)// declared 'a' in viewdidload as -1
      {
       ((UILabel*)detail).hidden = YES;
      }
    else if(a==indexPath.row)
       {
         ((UILabel*)detail).hidden = NO;
        }
       ((UILabel*)detail).hidden = YES;



return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    a=indexPath.row;

[tableview reloadData];


 }
```

Sorry for posting large amount of codes, it may help any one who is searching for the wholesome data of my doubt.

Whats the mistake am doing, I can't hide the detail label for resp selecting of cells. Can anybody help in this regard?

Comment: add [self.tableview beginUpdates]; and [self.tableview endUpdates]; in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, my problem is solved... thanks @helper for our suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to use xcode functionnality to design your cell content? (as easy as drag and drop of UILabel on your cell for example) Then you will be able to access them from your code using their respective "tag" id.
A correct way of doing is detail here : http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/
I think it's a better way than programmatically creating content for your cell, because using xcode interface you will be able to flawlessly define your interface.

Anyway to respond precisely to your question you should try to hide the detail label from "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" :

```
// Retrieve the corresponding cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Get the detail label (using its tag) you set it to 1002
UILabel *detail = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1002];

// Hide it
detail.hidden = true;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: ya first i tried with using the subtitle style to place text in tableviewcell, but running the position of text are misplaced, so trying for the manual creation of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your logic. You code as written will always set detail.hidden to YES, the 2 preceding if are ignored, thus this (BTW you don't need the type coercion and extra brackets):

> if(a==-1) detail.hidden = YES;
>   else if (a==indexPath.row) detail.hidden = NO;
>   **else** detail.hidden = YES;